# How to fix select drop down menu on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code snippet. I'm facing an issue on mobile device. The drop down menu doesn't work at all. I've tried adding classes, tried @media query css for smaller devices, and a number of other things that didn't work. I'm beginning to suspect that it could be because of the many layers of div elements that I have?

When I try to touch/tap the drop down menu on a mobile device, the options don't show up. It feels like the drop down menu is disabled or something, but it works perfectly on a desktop. I'm trying to find a solution that keeps the drag and drop/sorting feature implemented.

```js
 /** Add sortable/draggable function **/
        $('.column').sortable({
            connectWith: '.column',
            cursor: 'move',
            placeholder: 'placeholder',
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            opacity: 0.4,
            stop: function(event, ui)
            {
                /** Increment or decrement value based on element position **/
                $('.currentposition').each(function (i) {
                    let numbering = ++i + 4;
                    $(this).val(numbering);

                });

                /** Display ordering priority number **/
                $('.current_position').each(function (i) {
                    let numbering = ++i + 4;
                    $(this).text(numbering);

                });
            }
        }).disableSelection();
```

```css
.column .dragbox{
        margin:5px 2px  20px;
        position: relative;
        border:1px solid #946553;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    }
    .column .dragbox{
        margin:0;
        /*font-size:12px;*/
        color:#fff;
        border-bottom:1px solid #946553;
        font-family:Verdana;
        cursor:move;
        padding:5px;
    }

    .dragbox-content{
        margin:5px;
        font-family:'Lucida Grande', Verdana;
        font-size:0.8em;
        line-height:1.5em;
    }
    .column .placeholder{
        background: #EED5B7;
        border:1px dashed #946553;
    }

    .opIcons
    {
        background-image: url('iconSpirite.gif')!important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float:right;
        height:13px;
        width:13px;
        margin:0px 2px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


<div id="column1" class="column ui-sortable">

<div class="dragbox" id="item5">

<div class="dragbox-content"></div>

<div class="setting">

<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;">
<label style="margin-left: 8px;" for="contact_information_requested-first_name_chatbot">Lastname:</label>
</div>

<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;">
<select class="dropdown-toggle" style="width: 95%" name="Quote[95009][value]" data-form-type="address,country">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Don't Ask This Question</option>
<option value="1">Request This From User</option>
<option value="2">Require User to Provide This</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;"><input class="currentposition" type="hidden" size="1" name="Quote[95009][priority]" value="5">

<label class="current_position">5</label>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>

</div>

<div class="dragbox" id="item6">

<div class="dragbox-content"></div>

<div class="setting">

<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;">
<label style="margin-left: 8px;" for="contact_information_requested-first_name_chatbot">Zipcode:</label>
</div>

<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;">

<select class="dropdown-toggle" style="width: 95%" name="Quote[95010][value]" data-form-type="address,country">

<option value="0" selected="selected">Don't Ask This Question</option>
<option value="1">Request This From User</option>
<option value="2">Require User to Provide This</option>

</select>
</div>
</div>

<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;">
<input class="currentposition" type="hidden" size="1" name="Quote[95010][priority]" value="6">

<label class="current_position">6</label>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>

</div>

<div class="dragbox" id="item7">

<div class="dragbox-content">

</div>

<div class="setting">

<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;">
<label style="margin-left: 8px;" for="contact_information_requested-first_name_chatbot">Phone:</label>
</div>

<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;">

<select class="dropdown-toggle" style="width: 95%" name="Quote[95011][value]" data-form-type="phone,country">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Don't Ask This Question</option>
<option value="1">Request This From User</option>
<option value="2">Require User to Provide This</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;"><input class="currentposition" type="hidden" size="1" name="Quote[95011][priority]" value="7">

<label class="current_position">7</label>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>

</div>

<div class="dragbox" id="item8">

<div class="dragbox-content"></div>

<div class="setting">
<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;">
<label style="margin-left: 8px;" for="contact_information_requested-first_name_chatbot">Firstname:</label>

</div>

<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;">
<select class="dropdown-toggle" style="width: 95%" name="Quote[95008][value]" data-dashlane-rid="dfa7f355a521619d" data-form-type="other">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Don't Ask This Question</option>
<option value="1">Request This From User</option>
<option value="2">Require User to Provide This</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div style="font-weight:bold; width: 33%; float: left;">
<input class="currentposition" type="hidden" size="1" name="Quote[95008][priority]" value="8">

<label class="current_position">8</label>

</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clearly stated. Please edit your question to improve its readability.

Comment: @CannedMan when I try to tap/touch the drop down menu on a mobile device, the options don't display, but this works perfectly on a desktop. And I need to keep the drag and drop/sorting feature implemented.

Answer (score -1):

It’s because of your Javascript. Please try to add this jquery file:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I hope this works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. To make this a helpful answer, please explain what you have done.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds oddly similar to a problem I had when trying to display my **embedded audio file** I put into my post.

I copied the code from my Google Drive Account **(after I clicked on the menu tab to get the javaS code,** went to the code editor of an article post I had there.

To my dismay, I was trying to get it to play, but noticed I couldn't get the play button to work.

Like you I was frustrated, so I went back into code editor mode **(HTML)** and started tinker around with the code itself, I thought it might be a certain  or maybe some **"whitespace"** in the code that could have been interfering with the functionality of the code itself.

And come to find out it was neither!

The problem I was having was a **"size-display issue"** that was affecting the audio player's ability to play; I caught onto to the issue and went back into my HTML Editor and simply **"adjusted the width and height"** of the player itself.

[Audio File  (size adjustment trick helped me fix) which allow the display size of my audio player properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG7qP.jpg)

[Audio Player (displayed correctly and now playable after adjusting the pixel size - width and height)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vzhk.jpg)

And sure enough, I was able to access the play button clicking it on and off properly without further issues.

That might be your issue, maybe if you adjusted the width, height, or both in terms of size -  it may be an  tag source code that may also hold a clue to your issue.

The auto player on my site is coded this way --

I'm just trying give a clue to what might be the problem, and it may give you a bit more insight to finding a notable solution.

***I hope this will be helpful to you! :D***